# pause in alexa sdk v2 responsebuilder

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

In Alexa V1 a pause can be easily built in response by using ssml.

```
this.emit(':tell', "Pause now <break time='1s'/>. Start again");
```

But in Alexa SDK V2, the code (encoding the special characters):

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak( "Pause now &lt;break time="1s"/&gt;. Start again")
      .getResponse();
  },
```

gives the response without the pause, but repeating the sentence below.
"Pause now . Start again"

How do we then put a pause in response builder of Alexa SDK v2?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like syntax issues. I have tested a similar snippet in my test skill. This should work well.

```
handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Pause now <break time="1s"/>. Start again')
      .getResponse();
},
```

Comment: You are right! Simple things work. Got confused with the [official document](https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Building-Response.html) which says: "The contents of the speak and reprompt values get wrapped in SSML tags. This means that any special XML characters within the value need to be escape coded. For example, handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak("I like M&M's") will cause a failure because the & character needs to be encoded as &amp;. Other characters that need to be encoded include: < -> &lt;, and > -> &gt;."

Comment: Thanks, I had trouble finding any examples for Alexa ASK SSML syntax in nodejs working directly in the .speech() command.